# Embedding Gnash into PyGame?

Tags: python, flash, pygame, gnash

Is there a way to display flash applications using Gnash renderer (I'm not averse to Adobe's renderer but would prefer not to use it) in a PyGame application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Gnash allow drawing to an SDL_Surface? If so, Pygame has a C API that would make gluing these together easy. If not your best bet will be Pygame's [frombuffer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer) command. This will interepret a raw block of data as an image. You'll still need some way of getting that pointer from Gnash to your Python code.

Comment: So Pygame does allow drawing to an SDL_Surface but how do you return user interaction to the Gnash app?

Comment: It sounds like you want to switch back and forth between Pygame and Gnash? This may be tricky, because of knowing which library should "own" the window.

It would make more sense to see if SDL and Gnash can work together. Once they are happy, Pygame will add no difficulty.